# Can an author choose the reviewer of their book?

Tags: publications, peer-review, journals, books

I suspect the answer is no. The problem is, there is a group of scholars who would invariably trash the works of young scholars from a certain school of thought (they already did).

My book was recently published by a reputable publisher. A journal editor contacted me, as he would like to have an academic review of my book (to be published in the journal).

This is my first experience of having a book published and reviewed. Can I tell the journal editor not to ask (insert a couple of scholars' name) to review my book, as they would just trash it?

Can I propose some names - academics who are not my friends, but are more neutral and not dead set against a certain school of thought?

Or is it entirely up to the editor to ask any scholar to review, and it would be unprofessional of me to suggest anything?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can and you should.

Comment: You can always ask, the editor may simply not agree!

Comment: It would seem likely that the editor would know of such a clash of schools of thought?

Comment: At some journals I submitted papers to, they actively ask you for suggestions for suitable reviewers and also ask for people you don't want to do the review (you don't have to give a reason). So this kind of thing is not uncommon.

Comment: Seems pretty unusual - why would they need your permission to review your book?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can suggest people to review and to not review your work. It is the editor's decision, however. Most editors would probably appreciate your suggestions.

Be prepared to give reasons, however. Prior attacks on your work or that of your colleagues would probably be a valid reason to object.

But, you don't get to make the choice.